# How to create a macro to copy data from one excel worksheet to the next line in another worksheet

Tags: excel, copy, vba

I'm a bit stumped with this and wondered if anyone could help please? I've created a macro in excel to copy some data from one worksheet to another. It works fine, but obviously each time I run the macro, it just completes the top line (as I pasted to whilst recording). I actually want it work so that every time I run the macro, it copies the data to a new line.

If it helps, I can paste a link to the document. I'm sure it's just a case of pasting some VBA code into the macro. At the moment, the code looks like this:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Sheets("Quotation System").Select
    Range("K9").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Confirmed Bookings").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("B2").Select
    Sheets("Quotation System").Select
    Range("K11").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Confirmed Bookings").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Quotation System").Select
    Range("K13").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Confirmed Bookings").Select
    Range("C2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Quotation System").Select
    Range("K15").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Confirmed Bookings").Select
    Range("D2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Columns("D:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Columns("D:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Columns("D:D").ColumnWidth = 10.86
    Sheets("Quotation System").Select
    Range("K17").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Confirmed Bookings").Select
    Range("E2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("F2").Select
    Sheets("Quotation System").Select
    Range("K19").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Confirmed Bookings").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Columns("F:F").ColumnWidth = 8.57
    Sheets("Quotation System").Select
    Range("K21").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Confirmed Bookings").Select
    Range("G2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("H2").Select
    Sheets("Quotation System").Select
    Range("K23").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Confirmed Bookings").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("I2").Select
    Sheets("Quotation System").Select
    Range("K25").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Confirmed Bookings").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Quotation System").Select
    Range("K7").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Confirmed Bookings").Select
    Range("J2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("K2").Select
    Sheets("Quotation System").Select
    Range("G29").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Confirmed Bookings").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Columns("K:K").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Columns("K:K").ColumnWidth = 6
    Columns("K:K").ColumnWidth = 7
    Range("K2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Quotation System'!R[27]C[-4]"
    Range("K3").Select
    Columns("J:J").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Range("I19").Select
    Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 8.43
End Sub
Sub Booking_confimred()

End Sub
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Because you have a very situation-specific macro recorded, I would like to show you just a basic method to improve this macro and place those copies to a specific position:

You start with this

```
Public Sub Macro1()

  Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

then, this is what macro-recoder uses to copy:

```
Sheets("Quotation System").Select
Range("K9").Select
Selection.Copy
```

This is what you can use instead:

```
Sheets("Quotation System").Range("K9").Copy
```

This is what macro-recorder uses to paste:

```
Sheets("Confirmed Bookings").Select
Range("A2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

This is what you can use instead:

```
Sheets("Confirmed Bookings").Range("A2").Paste
```

And in order to paste it to a new line, it would be like

```
   With Sheets("Confirmed Bookings")
     .Cells(.UsedRange.Columns(1).Rows.Count + 1, 1).Paste
   End With
```

However, this is not the only way to solve this, and sureley not the best one, but it might help you at your level of understanding VBA.

If you want a neater solution, you might want to search around on SO, as there are many similar questions/problems and good solutions to them here.